# Alguien sabe como obtener el carácter del medio

Tags: c#, array, string, split, caracteres

Alguien sabe como obtener el caracter del medio de una cadena por ejemplo de un nombre :JUANA
Y EL CARACTER DEL MEDIO SERIA LA :  A

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! seguro que si! con substring.. que intentaste? que problema tuviste?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

*Deberias intentar por tu cuenta antes de pedir la solucion y sino sale pones el código de lo que hayas intentado.*
*Cada cadena tienen una propiedad llamada `Length`, que es la longitud de una cadena.*
Ejemplo :

```
J u a n a
0 1 2 3 4
```

*Considerando la longitud de la cadena deberias hacer una division.
Con esto deberias solucionar tu problema.*